# Understand the side effect of modifying the backing collection of a stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wrote the following code to test the side effect of modifying the backing collection of a stream

```
List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 11, 21));
x.stream().filter(i -> {
                  if (i < 10) {
                      x.remove(i); 
                      return false;
                  }
                  return true;
}).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output will be

```
21
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can anyone tell me what's going here? In particular, where is the NullPointerException coming from? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look into [`Collectors.partioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-)

Answer (score 8):

Your are violating the [contract of `filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) by passing an interfering predicate.  See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference) for a good explanation of the non-interference requirement.  It specifically says:

> The need for non-interference applies to all pipelines, not just parallel ones. Unless the stream source is concurrent, modifying a stream's data source during execution of a stream pipeline can **cause exceptions, incorrect answers, or nonconformant behavior**.

So the answer to your question is that the version of java you are running failed in that particular way with that particular data due to some unspecified implementation detail.  A different version of java might fail in some other way or not throw anything and produce the answer you expected or produce an incorrect answer.

You can try it with a `Collection` that is specified to produce a  CONCURRENT spliterator:

```
Collection<Integer> x = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(Arrays.asList(1, 11, 21));
```

It should do what you expect and not throw any exceptions.

Comment: this is entirely correct (1+), but these weekly consistent spliterators are completely non-intuitive when violating the spec, for example: `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        chm.put("one", 1);
        chm.forEach((x, y) -> chm.put(x + x, y + y));` Can you predict the output?

Comment: @Eugene "Doctor, doctor, it hurts when I do this." Doctor: "Then don't ***do*** that."

Answer (score 6):

To understand it lets make a schema about what happen exactly :

Your list look like this :

```
+---+       +---+       +---+      
| 1 |  -->  |11 |  -->  |21 |
+---+       +---+       +---+
  0           1           2
```

Now the filter is work which will iterate over your list index by index

First Iteration (index = 0, i = **1**)

check if `i < 10` -> yes then remove it from the list. now look like this :

```
+---+       +---+       +-----+      
|11 |  -->  |21 |  -->  |null |
+---+       +---+       +-----+
  0           1           2
```

Second Iteration (index = 1, i = **21** not 11)

check if `i < 10` -> yes then remove it from the list. now look like this :

```
+---+       +-----+       +-----+      
|21 |  -->  |null |  -->  |null |
+---+       +-----+       +-----+
  0            1             2
```

Third Iteration (index = 2, i = **null**)

check if `i < 10` which mean `null < 10` -> This will throw `NullPointerException`.

---

The question now, why you do that? all you need is just :

```
x.removeIf(i -> i < 10);
x.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: It is even worse - as the terminal operation is `forEach` and not `forEachOrdered`, it is not guaranteed that the iteration happens in this order.

Comment: Thank you @YCF_L  for your detailed explanation. I now have a deeper understanding of Java streams, after experimenting thought examples.

Comment: I agree with @Hulk that there is no guarantee. For example, when I change the list to Arrays.asList(1, 10, 11, 21), the output becomes 11, NullPointerException, 21. If what YCF_L said is correct, we should expect to get 11, 21, NullPointerException.

Comment: @student Yes I agree too with @Hulk the global idea in my answer is to explain what happen In your situation In any case you get `NullPointerException` :)